# working with strings issue android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi I am trying to create a sqlite query for my app, I need to read a txt string, split the string in single words and create the query  this is my code

```
s= “my string with some words”;
String aWords[] = s.split(" "); 
String querysearch = “body like ‘%” + aWords[0]+ "%'";
if((aWords[1] != null) && (aWords[1].length() > 3)) {querysearch = querysearch + " or      body like  '%" + aWords[1]+ "%'";}
if((aWords[2] != null) && (aWords[2].length() > 3)) {querysearch = querysearch + " or  body like  '%" + aWords[2]+ "%'";}
```

the app crashes here

```
if((aWords[1] != null) && (aWords[1].length() > 3))
```

and i do not understand why, it should just check if the string is empty and at least 4 chars long

any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: Can you provide the exception thrown?

Comment: What is the exception? It will be easy, if you add the log trace here.. Also try printing the aWords array and see if you got the split string correctly.

Comment: This code compiles and runs fine on my machine, producing the expected output. Please provide the exception thrown in order for us to help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it crashes, then your array has less than two elements. Just add a `aWords.length > 1` to your condition.